# Is there any way to do a database diagram in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm making a C# windows form application which is connected to a sql database; one of the easier ways I've found to create relationships to each table in a database is by using database diagrams.

I've noticed that visual studio 2012 doesn't have the database diagram feature though, is there any way to add this feature for visual studio 2012 or have microsoft re-add the feature to newer versions of visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this does not exist in Visual Studio. If you are using SQL Server, you can do this in SSMS quite easily.

1. Right click on Database Diagrams
2. Click New Database Diagram
3. Add all the tables you want and click add.
4. Press close for it to reorganize itself

Check this out as well [Did Microsoft remove database diagrams from Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567181/did-microsoft-remove-database-diagrams-from-visual-studio-2013)